# how add autocomplete option in editor using angular-ui-ace

Tags: angularjs, web, ace-editor

I am using aungular-ui-ace to create a code editor in my web site. All is fine, but I want include autocomplete option. The option {enableBasicAutocompletion: true} dont work for me.

My Code:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.ace']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){});
```

```html
<head>
   <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js"></script>
</head>  

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ui-ace="{mode: 'javascript', enableBasicAutocompletion: true}"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see advanced-options section of the readme https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace#advanced-options

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.ace']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){});
```

```html
<head>
   <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>-->
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/assets/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/ace.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/dist/ui-ace.js"></script>
</head>  

<style>
.ace_editor  {
  height : 200px;
}
</style>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ui-ace="{mode: 'javascript', 
   require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
   advanced: {
      enableSnippets: true,
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableLiveAutocompletion: true
  }}"></div>
</body>
```